# Deploy Azure function from code (c#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

**How to deploy azure function (executed on schedule) with code as string (in c#) to given azure functions app?**

I am going to use ARM template to deploy azure fund app (+ all it needs) https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-function-app-create-dynamic, which can be deployed via code;

But I don't see ways to deploy function to function app via code.

*+ A little more context*: deployment is going to happen from an app service, so it's preferred not to have any dependencies beyond NuGet. E.g. I don't like the idea to call azure cli from c#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jesse Carter mentioned that we could use [Kudu Zip Api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to do that. I do a demo for that. It works correctly on my side. The following is my detail steps:

**Preparation:**

Registry an AD application and assign role to applcation, more details please refer to [Azure official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). After that we can get tenantId, appId, secretKey from the Azure Portal.

1.Prepare an authentication file, we could get more information from github [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Fluent/AUTH.md).

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

2.Zip the need to be published file

**Steps:**

1.Create a C# console project

2.Reference the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent/), more detail info please refer to the packages.config file section.

3.Add the following code in the Program.cs file

```
   var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"authentication file path");
   var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();
   var webFunctionAppName = "azure function name";
   var webFunctionApp = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.List().Where(x => x.Name.Equals(webFunctionAppName))?.First();
   var ftpUsername = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetById(webFunctionApp.Id).GetPublishingProfile().FtpUsername;
   var username = ftpUsername.Split('\\').ToList()[1];
   var password = azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.GetById(webFunctionApp.Id).GetPublishingProfile().FtpPassword;
   var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
   var file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"zip file path");
   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
        var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webFunctionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
        var requestURl = baseUrl+ "api/zip/site/wwwroot";
        var httpContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        var response = client.PutAsync(requestURl, httpContent).Result;
     }
```

4.Test from the local

[image]

5.Check the published result from the Azure kudu tool(https://yourazurefunctionanme.scm.azurewebsites.net/)

[image]

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerRegistry.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DocumentDB.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Anyone having issues with deploying serviceBusTrigger functions to an existing function app suing the above kudu api example? After deploying, the function app's trigger are manually synced using the second trigger syncing option found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to deploy the function itself directly from code as opposed to using a CI/CD pipeline then your best bet is to use the [Kudu REST APIs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to upload the function code as a zip to the running function app. You should be able to make do using HttpClient or any of the other .NET REST libraries.

Comment: Could you please provide any insight of how to authenticate for this access in a just-created azure functions app?

Comment: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials There's tons of information in the docs. Authentication is outside of the context of your question I recommend that you take some time to actually read through the docs try some different things. If you have specific problems with code further down then ask a new question

Comment: We've gone through many documentation pages. However, none of it covers obtaining credentials for app via code.